# Why was the Kerch strait bridge built along a long route?

Tags: russian-federation, crimea, transportation

Russia just completed construction of a very long [bridge across the Kerch strait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crimean_Bridge_(Crimea)) - 23km.

I was wondering - why didn't it build the bridge along the shorter route, from [Chushka port](https://goo.gl/maps/1TitRZGg2FM2), where the ferry runs? That seems to be less than half the distance for the bridge. Is the reason political, economic or engineering-related?

[image]

Comment: Wikipedia’s article about the [Kerch Strait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerch_Strait) suggests technical reasons: *Since 1944, various bridge projects to span the strait have been proposed or attempted, always hampered by the difficult geologic and geographic configuration of the area.* Unfortunately, no details and no source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, because the shorter route would [interfere with the shipping lane](https://www.tunneltalk.com/Crimea-20May2015-Bored-tunnel-favoured-for-a-fixed-link-across-the-Kerch-Strait.php).

Although you can't exactly rule out the possibility that corruption plays a role; the bridge has been built by SGM group, which is owned by Putin's close friend Arkady Rotenberg. Finding evidence is of course impossible.